# while loop until input is has fulfilled two statements

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
def ask_input(prompt, error):
    while True:
        value = input(prompt)
        try:
            int(value) > 1
            break
        except ValueError:
            print(error)
        else:
            return value
```

So I want to make simple function that returns value if its integrel and greater than 1. So far the function seems to accept anything I put in. Do I need to make multiple loops or can I integrate both of statement in a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if` statement:

```
while True:
    value = input(prompt)
    try:
        if int(value) > 1:
            return int(value)  # return the value if condition met
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: Won't this fall though to the `else` after the try in case the value is < 1? Should make clear that the `else` is to be removed in this case.

Comment: @tobias_k, You're right. I modified the code. Thank you for pointing.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Added print(error) to else -statement and it turned exactly like wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **try/except** to accept only integers. Then test the input for the greater than 1 condition using an `if` condition, return the value if it satisfies the condition. It's better to use `raw_input()` in this case as you want an integer literal as input, where as `input()` can also evaluate expressions potentially leading to unsanitized input.

```
def ask_input(prompt, error):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(raw_input(prompt))
            if value > 1:  # Return the number if it's greater than 1.
                return value
        except ValueError:  # Catch exception if value is not a base 10 int. 
            print error
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code prompts the user for anything that can be converted to an integer, whether or not it is > 1, then return None. This is not what you intended.

There are 2 different problems here:

```
int(value) > 1
```

If the input value is not parsable as an integer, then this will raise a ValueError that you catch and handle properly.
If the input value is parsable as an integer, then `int(value)` will convert it to an actual integer which will be compared to 1. The result of this comparison, however, is completely ignored since it is not stored in a variable or used.

Then the `break` will immediately leave the `while` loop, then the end of `ask_input` is reached, without a return statement. Because of that the `else` clause of your `try` is ignored.

I suggest the following code:

```
def ask_input(prompt, error):
    while True:
        value = input(prompt)
        try:
            if int(value) > 1:
                return value
        except ValueError:
            print(error)
```